# Modify HTML called from function's shortcode in Wordpress post

Tags: javascript, custom-wordpress-pages

Changing HTML called from a function on Wordpress

I'm trying to modify the HTML called from a function's shortcode in a Wordpress post. This function sends all the informations of the page like images, text and calendar widget and i want to change the information it sends to show only images and remove the HTML div containing the text and the calendar.

Unfortunately i don't have access to the code since it's not in the wordpress files but comes from a 3rd party system, so i was wondering if i could change the html that the function calls after the page has fully loaded.

As of now i've tried to add a function to remove the HTML text div class as follows:

```
`function removeElementsByClass(tripInfoContent){
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(tripInfoContent);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
    window.onload = function removeElementsByClass();
}`
```

The shortcode is "package_details" for the "packageDetails" function.

Is it possible to change the HTML after being loaded?

Comment: I think the line `window.onload = function removeElementsByClass();` should be outside the function

Comment: Tried you suggestion, but it didn't worked

Comment: maybe (always outside the function): `window.onload = removeElementsByClass;` this should work

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately, thanks for the help though